# Javascript array.filter by element in children

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, children

I have an Array of objects (clients) like this:

```
"{"client_id":"AAA1","contracts":[{"contract_id":"CON1-AAA1","revisions":[{"date":"2018-07-30","status":"First Sign"}]}]}"
```

I can filter by client_id with no problem:

```
var query = clients.filter(x => x.client_id == "AAA1");
```

However, I'd like to filter by revision date or status, I tested doing the following, but I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined"

```
var query = clients.filter(x => x.contracts.revisions.status == "First Sign");
```

Is it possible to do it this way or Im delusional? :)

Comment: `"{"client_id":"AAA1","contracts":[{"contract_id":"CON1-AAA1","revisions":[{"date":"2018-07-30","status":"First Sign"}]}]}"` is not an array. It is a string. Please provide a [mcve] using the `<>` button

Comment: @korocota pls provide the proper JSON if it is!

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve that by using a combination of an [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and two [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) :

```js
const clients = [{
  "client_id": "AAA1",
  "contracts": [{
    "contract_id": "CON1-AAA1",
    "revisions": [{
      "date": "2018-07-30",
      "status": "First Sign"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "client_id": "AAA2",
  "contracts": [{
    "contract_id": "CON1-AAA2",
    "revisions": [{
      "date": "2018-08-30",
      "status": "Second Sign"
    }]
  }]
}];

let result = clients.filter(cl => cl.contracts.some(c => c.revisions.some(r => r.status == 'First Sign')));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: OP probably wants to filter the `clients`, not the `contracts`

Answer (score 0):

This happens since revisions and contracts is an array.

You will need to choose between any item equals to all items equals.

Using [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) - Any item in array answers a criteria.
Using [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) - All items in array answers a criteria.

Example for finding a client that has any contract with at least on revision with the "First Sign" status:

```
const query = clients.filter(x => x.contracts.some(c => c.revisions.some(r => r.status == "First Sign")));
```

Comment: `contracts` is an array too

Comment: `x.contracts.revisions` But `revisions` is not a property of `contracts`, `contracts` is an array

Comment: Yup, didn't notice that. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Client is an object with an identifier and an array of contracts, each contract has an identifier with an array of revisions, each revision has a date and status, if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` and `some` like below should work:

```js
var clients = [
{
    "client_id": "AAA1",
    "contracts": [
    {
        "contract_id": "CON1-AAA1",
        "revisions": [
        {
            "date": "2018-07-30",
            "status": "First Sign"
        }]
    }]
},
{
    "client_id": "AAA1",
    "contracts": [
    {
        "contract_id": "CON1-AAA1",
        "revisions": [
        {
            "date": "2018-07-30",
            "status": "Second Sign"
        }]
    }]
}]

var query = clients.filter(
    x => x.contracts.some(y => y.revisions.some(z => z.status == "First Sign")));

console.log(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, since your error message and problem description clearly indicates that what you've posted as a string (that looks like an object), really is an excerpt of a bigger array, you can do the following

```js
const arr = [{"client_id":"AAA1","contracts":[{"contract_id":"CON1-AAA1","revisions":[{"date":"2018-07-30","status":"First Sign"}]}]}];
const res = arr.filter(client => client.contracts.some(contract => contract.revisions.some(revision => revision.status === 'First Sign')));

console.log(res);
```