# How to filter an array from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have the following two datasets:

```
// This is based on what user input, usually they will just select 1 or 2.
var selected = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', ...] 

  var list = [
   {
      "properties":{
         "name" : "Example Name",
         "tags":{
            "multi_select":[
               {
                  "name":"alpha"
               },
               {
                  "name":"charlie"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
    ...
   // same same but many more objects with different tags each
]
```

Yes, it's super nested, but it comes from an API...

Anyway, so what I'm trying to do now is `filter()` it based on the selected terms, example,
If list tags contain "alpha, charlie" and "alpha" is selected, it would display object, but if "alpha and bravo" is selected, the object won't match.

So with fewer it can match, but when it gets narrowed don't it shouldn't match.

I tried the following:

```
let res = list.filter(hb => hb.properties.Tags.multi_select.some(tag => tag.name.includes(selected)));
console.log(res);
```

This code is largely from [Javascript array.filter by element in children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589685/javascript-array-filter-by-element-in-children)

So I noticed, if I have selected "charlie" it returns the correct objects(s) that contains tag "charlie", but when I select more than 1, eg "charlie" and "alpha" it returns nothing even though there is suppose to be matching objects.

Any suggestions how I could improve the filtering?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what if `multi_select` contains more than the two wanted names?

Comment: @NinaScholz that's fine... it should still match... as long as the wanted names from selected doesn't contain something that doesn't exist in multi_select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check every selected tag agains some `name` of the filtering object.

```
let res = list.filter(hb => selected.every(tag =>
    hb.properties.tags.multi_select.some(({ name }) => name === tag)
));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the argument of your `includes` method here shouldn't be an array here, the check should rather be other way around.

```js
let res = list.filter(hb => hb.properties.tags.multi_select.some(tag => selected.includes(tag.name));
```

Also, one suggestion - It might be more optimal to use `Set` instead of `Array` for this use case maybe, if you want to research a bit.

As to why your code is working when you are only having one item, the reason is that the `selected` array undergoes a string conversion so `["charlie"]` becomes `charlie` which is returned as true as `charlie` is your first element in the `multiselect` array. But when you add another item, it happens like this `["alpha", "charlie"]` is casted to `"alpha,charlie"` which is concatenation of two items, so it would naturally return `false`.